# Bounty etiquette - early awards

Tags: discussion, bounty, etiquette

I've put a bounty on someone else's question and there has been a good answer posted. Would it be frowned upon to award the bounty to this answer even though there are still 5 days left in the bounty period? I know there's nothing *technically* wrong with this, just wondering what society expects of me!

Comment: I think it's only fair to other users to mention (in a comment maybe) that you're satisfied with the answer you received, so that people who are about to put in a lot of effort to find a different answer know where they stand. (I recently followed a question where the user who eventually got the bonus posted a second version of his answer, only to be told afterwards that the first version was already good enough.)

Comment: I already encountered people saying that they regretted having already awarded the bounty. To me, early awarding is reducing the worth of the bounty, so the awarding people hurt themselves.

Comment: And really, you can think the answer is good, but, it is not really replying the question. It is explaining a confusion in the question. Maybe someone could even come with a workaround that would make it an even more proper answer. For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810218/how-to-set-verify-peer-name-false-ssl-context-option-via-php-ini-in-php-5-6/37402437#37402437

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I'm not sure whether people will see it as *polite* or just nice, but I would leave the bounty going, especially if the answer was very good. The reasons for this are two-fold:

1. An *even better* answer could be posted that might deserve the bounty more. Regardless if you think this is possible or not, you might be surprised.
2. A better reason, in my mind, is how the ordering for bounties in the featured tab works. The closer to ending a bounty is, the higher on the featured list the question gets. The higher the question is, the more likely it is to get more views. If you leave the bounty up, then as the question gets higher to the list, it could attract more views and potentially more upvotes for the answer. This rewards the answerer even more than just awarding your bounty would.

Comment: The second point is very important, I [once added a bounty to a question where the bounty was awarded early](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29871138/1708801) exactly because the answer in my view did not receive anywhere near the upvotes deserved for the quality of content that was added to the site. A lot of the upvotes came during the last day and half.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour now it got one more upvote.

Comment: continuing with point no. 2, it would also have the effect of garnering more visibility to better the chances of the better answer mentioned in point no. 1 being supplied; virtuous cycle

Comment: The second point is valid even if there is *no* good new answer after posting the bounty. I once placed a bounty [on Japanese.SE](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25109/11830) that unfortunately didn't attract any new answers, but it did give the question and top answers a few new upvotes.

Comment: Nice answer, really, I would also like to add that it wouldn't be fair if the bounty was ending and that was it. But there is a grace period in which the user opening the bounty can still assign it, and in my view that's exactly what this grace period is for. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323826/why-is-there-a-grace-period-for-bounties

Answer (score 37):

The ultimate answer is, "you can award the bounty whenever you feel like it", but bear in mind this also ties in with the reason you offered the bounty in the first place.

If you placed the bounty there to **attract attention**, then there's no incentive to award it early.  Someone else may come along and offer an even *better* answer which is worthy of the bounty.

If you've placed the bounty there to **gain an authoritative answer**, the reason above is still applicable; better information may be exposed and you get an opportunity to revel in it.

If you've placed the bounty to **award an *existing* answer**, I would have the expectation that the bounty is temporal and could be awarded on a whim.