# Someone answered my question with a very useful response. I want it to get more exposure

Tags: discussion, bounty, upvotes

How can I make sure that the visibility of this answer is aligned with its value?

[How to serialize ANY object into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448604/how-to-serialize-any-object-into-a-string)

Someone answered with an incredibly useful and detailed response, but if I accept it now, won't it just kind of get lost in the noise?  Can I award an unsolicited bounty to bump it up or should I just accept and let the SO magic run its course?

Comment: `"Can I award an unsolicited bounty to bump it up..."` -- there ya go, only it will be a "solicited" bounty, one solicited by *you*.

Comment: Oh wait, you want to improve the visibility of the *answer*. That I don't know, but no don't go the bounty route since that is for increasing the visibility of your *question*. Be sure that your question is well tagged most of all, and is as clear and concise as possible, so that the question is as canonical as possible.

Comment: This isn't reddit. People looking for your post will find it if they need it.

Comment: Linked question seem to lack MCVE... and not exactly clear (also answer is nice). You really should think twice before asking for visibility of question before getting it in shape.

Comment: meta effect may already have you covered for getting more attention

Comment: As a rule of thumb accept answers at least several hours if not the day after you asked the question. This gives people more time to provide more answers, improve the existing ones and to the community to vote. There's no rush for accepting...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There *is* a bounty reason for a good answer that you've already received. The reason is "Reward Existing Answer", and you can leave it up for the full length of the bounty to draw attention to the answer. Feel free to accept the answer before hand, that won't affect the visibility of the question/answer in the bounty list.

[A related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323729/bounty-etiquette-early-awards) was asked a couple days ago about awarding a bounty early. Using the same logic from the answer there, bountying your question *specifically* to reward an existing answer and leaving the bounty up can result in increased exposure, and therefore increase votes, for the answer.

A couple things to keep in mind if you do decide to go this route:

1. Your *question* will also have increased exposure. Is it ready to be presented to more people? Are there ways to you can edit your question to clean it up? You may want to review it and be sure before posting the bounty. (Note: I have not actually read your question. This is general advice.)
2. Other people may not agree with you about the quality of the answer. Much like the "Meta Effect", the bounty exposure *could* cut the other way. But at least with the bounty, the answerer has a pretty good chance of coming out ahead- You'll be giving them the rep from the bounty, after all.
3. This *may* take a while. It's likely to take the majority of the bounty time before views really start coming in on the question, and therefore the answer.
4. You may get another answer, regardless of picking the "Reward Exisiting" bounty reason. Keep an open mind if this happens, as the new answer *could* potentially be better than the answer you're hoping to reward. I'm not saying this is *likely* with this bounty reason, but it could happen.

Keeping all this in mind, it's within appropriate use of the system to bounty your question for this answer. The only question remaining is whether you feel the answer deserves your bounty or not, regardless of whether it gets the increased attention you're hoping for.

---

Now that your Meta question has appeared in the Community Bulletin, you may not need to bounty your Stack Overflow question. The "Meta Effect" from linking your question here, and from three days worth of random appearances in the "Hot Meta Posts" (Provided your question here stays at 3 or higher score), will likely garner the attention you were hoping for.

Keep in mind that point 2 above also applies to the Meta Effect: It's not always positive, even if you're expecting it to be. Your question or the answer could both receive some downvotes from the extra attention, or they may just receive upvotes.

Comment: What if I want *this* answer to get more exposure?  Just kidding.  Thank you.