# Why is there a grace period for bounties?

Tags: support, bounty

I wanted to get a better understanding of what the bounty system was and how it worked so I read the [Help Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) for bounties.

It says *"there is a "grace period" of 24 hours to manually award the bounty"*.

What purpose does this "grace period" serve? Is it different to the original 7 days you have to award the bounty? Do you get other options for the bounty in these 24 hours?

Comment: Simply so that, once the bounty period has ended, you can take the time to choose the best answer, rather than needing to be online as the last minutes count down waiting for an even better answer like this was an eBay auction.

Comment: @RobertLongson: You can manually award a bounty at any time after the first 48 hours; however, as jonrsharpe mentions, this may not be ideal, given the possibility of late-arriving better answers.

Comment: It was added in 2011 after a lot of [whi^H^H^Hvalued feedback from the community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74037/144883).  Not so sure the "it can't hurt" assumption was accurate, the odds today you'll get an answer in less than 6 days are rather low.  Good Q+A does require the active participation of the questioner, at least a few back-and-forths to arrive at the correct solution.  But bounties are not exactly intended to produce good Q+A, they merely produce A's.

Comment: Someone answered my question after the grace period had expired. Can I file an appeal to award that person the bounty?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What purpose does this "grace period" serve?

After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty.

> Is it different to the original 7 days you have to award the bounty?

No, it gives you some extra time to choose the best answer.

Comment: There are *some* differences between the main bounty period and the grace period, although they don't affect manual awarding particularly.

Comment: @NathanTuggy *What are* the differences? I still don't understand the functional distinction between the original 7 day period and the 24 hour grace period. In my case [it doesn't seem to be helping](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/877/12102) to be told what they *are for*, I'd like to know how in what ways — if any —  they function differently.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I've asked [In what ways might a 7-day bounty plus 24 hour grace period be used differently than a straight 8-day bounty period?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349548/3904031) to get at this difference.