# In what ways might a 7-day bounty plus 24 hour grace period be used differently than a straight 8-day bounty period?

Tags: support, bounty

Having read the question [Why is there a grace period for bounties?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323826/3904031) and its [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346314/3904031), I'm still left puzzled, not really understanding the distinction between the original 7 day period and the 24 hour grace period. So I'd like to ask a related but somewhat different question, written in a way such that the answer will help me the most.

In order to get at, and then understand the *functional distinction* between the 7-day period and the grace period from the user's point of view I'd like to know *in what ways might a 7-day bounty plus 24 hour grace period be used differently than a straight 8-day bounty period?*

Are there any benefits, or differences at all in the way a user might be able to interact with the current 7 day + 24 hour grace system compared to a straight 8 day bounty?

From a user's point of view, does the bounty function or behave in any way differently during the 24-hour grace period than it did during the previous 7 days?

I am beginning to suspect that there is no functional difference, that the distinction is in name only. If that is in fact not the case, please describe the functional differences; just hearing about "what they are for" is not helping.

Comment: @jonrsharpe your (you're) too fast for me! Do you have a missing appostraphe detecting bot?

Comment: Answers posted during the last 24h are not eligible for the rep with 7d+24h but would be with 8d. This would make it difficult for the awarder to make a reasonable decision on something posted just before the end of the bounty period, as they'd have no time to evaluate it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what does "eligible for the rep" mean?

Comment: It means whether or not they can "win" the points that form the bounty. If you post during the grace period, I don't think you can be awarded the bounty. The point of the grace period is that it gives the awarder time to consider *all* of the answers posted during the bounty period.

Comment: @jonrsharpe wow that's a pretty potent statement! An answer posted during the grace period can not have the full bounty awarded? I'd like to know for sure if that's true. Also I'd like to know for sure if the 50% bounty auto-award feature would or would not work on an answer posted during the grace period.

Comment: Cannot have *any*, as far as I'm aware - *the bounty has finished*. The grace period is for the awarder, not the answerers, otherwise it would surely be pointless?

Comment: @jonrsharpe While this is somewhat helpful, by posting these statements as comments but not answers, I don't have any way to judge if they are true or not, and future readers won't either. Would you be willing post this clearly as a proper answer?

Comment: You have no more way to judge whether they're true if I write a comment, post an answer, publish a poster on the side of a bus or carve them in stone. I'm not sure, so I haven't posted an answer, but the above would make sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe answers get up votes and down votes and usually get more and finer overall scrutiny than comments, especially in meta. OK thanks for your help!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The principal distinction deals with two things:

1. The question stops being advertised as a bounty once the grace period starts. This means that it is now far less likely to get an answer than when it was being advertised.
2. If a user posts an answer during the unadvertised grace period, then only the person who set the bounty can cause it to be awarded to them. It is ineligible for the automatic system.

It basically prevents a data race. One person could be madly writing an answer, hoping to get it in and considered before the bounty period expires. While at the same time, the bounty holder is deciding which answer to award the bounty to.

With the grace period, the giver of the bounty can wait to consider answers until the bounty period has ended. Since the question is no longer advertised as having a bounty, they can feel reasonably assured that nobody else will be writing an answer with an expectation to be considered for it. Now, grace-period answers *can* be considered (but only by the poster of the bounty, not by the automatic system), but since they're clearly late, the person who posted them probably realized at the time that they may not be given due consideration.

That's one behavioral difference.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer, including the specific bulleted items. This gives me a much better understanding.