# Reward bounty only after three hours

Tags: support, bounty

After asking a question and getting great answer i wish to reward with the bounty the answer, but it's telling me to do so only 3 hours later... Why?  I don't understand the logic behind...

Thank you

Comment: A somewhat related question on the advantages of waiting to award a bounty: [Bounty etiquette - early awards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323729/bounty-etiquette-early-awards)

Comment: The logic is, someone else might come along with an *even better* answer. What's the rush to pick a winner?

Comment: There is no rush to award bounties nor to accept answers. Remember that questions and answers are meant to be useful to a vast number of people, not just you. So if your actions are so that people are discouraged to post new answers or improve the existing ones you are *harming* the community. I suggest you wait at least a few days before awarding bounties and at least 1 day for accepting answers.